# How to read directory in codeIgniter outside the application folder?

Tags: codeigniter

```
$dir = 'application/';
$map = directory_map($dir);
```

I am able to read directory inside the application folder with `directory_map`

but, not able to read system and other folder outside the application folder.....

```
$dir = '../application/';
$map = directory_map($dir);
```

Comment: you need to use it `$map = directory_map('./dir/');` where **dir is a folder in the root of your project structure**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FCPATH` is a constant that represent a path to CodeIgniter's root directory.

To access system directory, use:

```
    $dir = FCPATH . 'system';
    $map = directory_map($dir);
```